# Remove my website from google search results

Tags: seo, google

My website had a negative reference to it in comments on a prominent website. I contacted their admin (not the site owner who I cannot get hold of) and the comment was removed. However, 2 weeks later Google is still returning the old cached result, and this may well affect a potential partnership deal. Is there any way I can get Google to remove this? How long do I have to wait before it disappears?

Comment: This is NOT the same question. The other question is about someone removing their OWN website from Google. Im asking about removing a reference to my website from another website in Google Results. Not the same thing.

Comment: That's not really clear in the question, and questions here are required to be about [your own website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You can use the [Remove Outdated Content tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846?hl=en#make_permanent&zippy=%2Csee-removal-requests-from-non-owners). There is no indication of how long that would take, or guarantees that it will remove the cache, however it's usually pretty quick when it does in my experience (i.e., like a few days).

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what I was looking for!